# Process Class Not Found in System.Diagnostics? (System.dll???)

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, linker, compiler-errors

I am using .NET Framework 3.5, I have referenced all the assemblies, I have double checked everything, but still this irritating error

```
 CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Process' does not exist in the namespace               
 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (Proj1)
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  and various other sources, the Process class is definitely located in System.dll in the System.Diagnostics namespace. Then What In The World Is The Problem?

Comment: System.dll is definitely referenced in your project and for the right version? (v2.0.50727)

Comment: Targeting Silverlight or some-such?  You ask a lot of Mono questions too.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project in Visual Studio and checking whether you are able to reference Process class?

Comment: @AdamTuliper Thanks that fixed it. My IDE was referencing some other version. So i guess just post it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Your culprits are either a subset of .NET that does not include access to the Process class (WP7? Silverlight?), or Mono, which may handle that class differently.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm targeting GTK#. But not with Mono, as I said, I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: @SpikeX Yup , the System.dll my IDE was referencing was a different version.

Comment: How do you change which Dll is being referenced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you are referencing the correct System.Dll. The version should be roughly v2.0.50727

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. I was using CodeDom to execute code that required Process Class. So the solution for me was to refrence System.dll in options. Here is the solution, if any one needs it.

```
CSharpCodeProvider cs = new CSharpCodeProvider();
cs.CompilerOptions = "/optimize /reference:System.dll";
```